# why does turtle.circle(r,extent=720,steps=5) in python draws a star?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Today, I accidentally tested this code:

```
import turtle

turtle.circle(70,extent=720,steps=5)
```

and turtle drew this for me: [image: img]

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`turtle.circle` does not draw a circle. As [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle) in the official documentation,

> the circle is approximated by an inscribed regular polygon

Specifying `extent=720` says to draw 720 degrees of (approximated) circle, and specifying `steps=5` says to use a 5-sided polygon to approximate the circle. A 5-sided regular polygon that goes 720 degrees around is a standard 5-sided star.